# How to test stomp application using postman?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp

I am making a chat application backend using spring WebSockets.
The protocol for communication is STOMP and I am using rabbitmq as a message broker.

I want to test my application using postman but I can't find any helpful tutorial/video.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this post. I think it's usefull for your request.
https://dev.to/danielsc/testing-stomp-websocket-with-postman-218a

Basically you have to encode sokect message to Base64 and send it through postman by using its websocket feature